# What is the most efficient way to create draggable sortable lists in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create draggable ordered lists but according to [this blog](http://benw.me/posts/sortable-bootstrap-tables/) the acts_as_lists gem is very server intensive and it also says build failing. They suggest the ranked model gem however it appears to be deprecated.

So what is the most efficient way to do this without causing a huge load on the server when there are many users rearranging lists.

Comment: You could use [jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable).

Comment: That's what i plan on using but i need a way to update the database i am not sure how to do it efficiently. Like this rails cast https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aBsUkJMbmE shows the acts_as_list gem with jQuery but i want a more efficient way like ranked model.

Comment: JQuery drag n' drop and force the user to click a save button after he's satisfied with the arrangement of the list.

Comment: That would work. Do you know where i could find a guide on that. I assume i would use acts_as_list like that rails cast but figure out how to stop the automatic update and force a user to save somehow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use [HTML5 Sortable jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/voidberg/html5sortable/).

For each item, there is a **ordering** field to specify the ordering (1 to n). Once the draggable sorting is done by user, the ordering is posted to Rails backend in array, e.g. [1, 5, 3, 6, 2, 4]. The number in array is **id** of items. Based on this array, I can update the **ordering** field. For example, the first item (id = 1) in array has ordering 1, and second item (id = 5) has ordering 2. Later, you can use **order("ordering ASC")** for ordering.

First, there is a sort view (route is **get 'items/sort'**) for user to do draggable sorting. It look like this (in slim format):

```
div#items-sortable
  - @items.each do |item|
    = div_for item, data: {id: item.id}
      = item.title
      hr

= form_tag action: :ordering do
  = hidden_field_tag :items_ids, ""
  = submit_tag 'Save Changes'
```

The form is to keep the ordering array and allows data to be posted to Rails.

The Javascript (CoffeeScript) looks like this:

```
sortable_element = document.getElementById('items-sortable')
if sortable_element
  $(sortable_element).sortable({
    placeholder: "<div style='border-style: dashed'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>"
    })
    .bind('sortupdate', (e, ui) ->
      orders = ui.endparent.children().map( -> return $(this).data("id") ).toArray()
      document.getElementById('items_ids').value = JSON.stringify(orders)
    )
```

When user does the sorting, it keeps the hidden field of form updated with ordering of item id.

Once the sorting is done and user click "Save Changes" button, it is posted to route **items/ordering** with **item_ids** parameter. The method in controller looks like this:

```
def ordering
  if (@orders = params[:items_ids]) && (@orders.present?)
    @orders = JSON.parse(params[:items_ids])
    if @orders.kind_of?(Array) && @orders.size > 0
      # Let build hash for mass update
      data = {}
      @orders.each_with_index do |iden, index|
        data[iden] = {ordering: index}
      end
      Item.all.update(data.keys, data.values) # still update one-by-one at backend
    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to items_path }
  end
end
```

If you don't want to use form, you can try to convert it with AJAX.